# How to fill color in ccsprite with specified color?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm trying to draw a filled rectangle with specified color.

How to do that?

Following is tried code.

```
void MySprite::draw(void) 
{

    glLineWidth(1);
    ccDrawColor4F(255 / 255.0f , 0 / 255.0f , 0 / 255.0f , 200 / 255.0f);
    ccDrawRect(CCPointMake(0 , 0), CCPointMake(int_width , int_height));

    //How to fill in this rectangle?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this : `ccDrawSolidRect(CCPoint origin, CCPoint destination, ccColor4F color)`

Reference : [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.2/d6/da4/group__global.html#ga04713ae281f8feabaddea7a07c46a327)